# Python logging won't write to file

Tags: python, exception, error-logging

So I'm using an exception logging module I found and tweaked slightly. But I can't seem to figure out why it won't create a file and write to it.

This is my module:

```
"""Exception logging"""
import sys
import traceback
import logging

logger = logging
def setup_logging_to_file():
    logger = logging.basicConfig( filename='error_log.txt',
                                filemode='w',
                                level=logging.DEBUG,
                                format= '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                            )


def log_exception(e):
    logger.error(
    "Function {function_name} raised {exception_class} ({exception_docstring}): {exception_message}".format(
    function_name = extract_function_name(), #this is optional
    exception_class = e.__class__,
    exception_docstring = e.__doc__,
    exception_message = e.message))

def extract_function_name():
    tb = sys.exc_info()[-1]
    stk = traceback.extract_tb(tb, 1)
    fname = stk[0][3]
    return fname
```

I run `setup_logging_to_file()` on start up then whenever I hit an exception I call `log_exception` and pass it the exception but it won't even create the `error_log.txt` file

```
from app.exception_logging import log_exception, setup_logging_to_file

def myFunc():
    try:
        ....
    except Exception as ex:        
        log_exception(ex)
```

Comment: You should delete the extra comma on the `format` argument of `logging.basicConfig`. Also, when you call `log_exception()`, `logger` is a reference to `logging` and not the `logger` variable used in `setup_logging_to_file` because global variables are "read-only".You should use function argument. On other side, I don't understand why you wrote `logger = logging`: just use `logging`

Comment: What does it mean that you call `setup_logging_to_file` on startup? Where do you call it from?

Comment: I wanted to create a project wide logging module so that I can just call the `log_exception` function in any of my try/catch blocks. When I launch my project I call `setup_logging_to_file()` to initialize my logger variable but I changed this from what @Loïc G said

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. At the end I resolved to do as following:

```
import logging.config

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("log_file.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

And then in the code, you may use the logger as following:

```
logger.info('message')
logger.error('message')
```

Comment: can you explain why this works? i cant use any other method except this one

Comment: I imagine this works fine because of handlers. Handlers can work asynchronously in this case alongside of main flow of code, logging to file time by time!

Comment: 'Event handler is a callback routine that operates asynchronously once an event takes place.'

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments - you can access logging directly.

Working example, file called logtest.py:

```
"""Exception logging"""
import sys
import traceback
import logging

logging.basicConfig( filename='/tmp/error_log.txt',
                            filemode='w',
                            level=logging.DEBUG,
                            format= '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                )


def log_exception(e):
    logging.error(
    "Function {function_name} raised {exception_class} ({exception_docstring}): {exception_message}".format(
    function_name = extract_function_name(), #this is optional
    exception_class = e.__class__,
    exception_docstring = e.__doc__,
    exception_message = e.message))

def extract_function_name():
    tb = sys.exc_info()[-1]
    stk = traceback.extract_tb(tb, 1)
    fname = stk[0][3]
    return fname
```

destination file:

```
from logtest import log_exception

try:
   open("somthingnotthere",'r')
except Exception as ex:        
    log_exception(ex)
```

Comment: I have all my logging in it's own python file so that in my project I can just call the function in all my try/catch blocks

Comment: updated to show example with two files. What you were really doing wrong was within the setup_logging_to_file function. If you want to use that function. You need to pass in the logger object as a parameter.